# Vue and Javascript

Tags: vue.js

[1][Can not import?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwrsA.png)

I wanna link a js file with Vue imported on it to a html.
Is seems the html is linking correctly the script.js under the script tag but the javascript file cant understand Vue so the html cant do so.
Im very inexperienced, it is basic help.

Answer (score 0):

1. import Vue in index.html

```
<head>
  <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "/lib/vue.esm.browser.js_2.6.11/vue.esm-browser.js",
          "vue-multiselect":"/lib/vue-multiselect/vue-multiselect.esm.min.js",
          "SingleFileComponent":"/js/SingleFileComponent.js",
          "MultiSelectComponent":"/js/MultiSelectComponent.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>
```

2. create anchor in index.html

```
<div id="app">
    <multi-select-component></multi-select-component>
</div>

<div id="single">
    <single-file-component></single-file-component>
</div>

<script type="module">
      import { createApp } from 'vue'
      import VueMultiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
      import SingleFileComponent from "SingleFileComponent";
      import MultiSelectComponent from "MultiSelectComponent" 

      createApp({
        components: {
           MultiSelectComponent
         }
      })
      .component('multiselect', VueMultiselect)
      .mount('#app')
        
      createApp({
         components: {
            SingleFileComponent
          }
      })
      .mount('#single')
</script>
```

3. create single-file-component in SingleFileComponent.js

```
export default {
    template: `
      <div>
      <h1>Single-file JavaScript Component</h1>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
      </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Oh hai from the component'
        }
    },
}
```

4. create multi-select-component in MultiSelectComponent.js

```
export default {
    template: `
      <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options"></multiselect>
      <label>{{ value }}</label>`,
    data() {
        return {
            value: null, options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
        }
    }
}
```